# Global pointer to local literal: Access Violation

Tags: c++

I have this code

```
#include <iostream>
int *p=nullptr;

void sum(void)
{
    *p=100;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    sum();
    std::cout<<*p<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error"Unhandled exception at 0x009e140e in a.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

The pointer is global, should it not be visible to all the sub scope?
I dont get it, because i am a beginner, whats happening here?

Comment: Title says it all :-P ... There's never any space allocated for `p`.

Comment: Sorry its not a variable, its a literal , i'll correct it. But still the question remains

Comment: `access violation`. - you're writing to an invalid memory location. the code is perfectly fine, it's YOU who are doing something illegal: writing to a null pointer.

Comment: Why are people down voting this?  (S)he's a beginner asking a question.  Don't down vote this, please.

Comment: @supercheetah why do you think the question deserves upvotes or being left alone in particular?

Comment: I'm not saying it deserves up votes, but the point of SO is to ask questions about programming.  The only reason I consider down votes to be valid is if a question isn't a programming related question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but why downvotes?beginners not allowed here..?

Comment: @MiceZeusDig Most probably because lacking research and debugging efforts.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ research is a relative term , with enough research you can get answer to almost anything, and this site wouldnt exist..anyways i am outta here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *p=100;

Doesn't make `p` point to your *local literal*. It tries to dereference `nullptr` and assign a value, which leads to the exception you've noticed.

To make `p` point to a local literal you should have something like this

```
void sum() {
    static const int literal = 100;
    p = &literal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The pointer is visible. But it was set to nullptr. You may not dereference it.

To solve the problem you can write

```
int *p = new int();

void sum(void)
{
    *p=100;
}
```

But the better approach is the following

```
#include <memory>

//...

std::unique_ptr<int> p( new int() );

void sum(void)
{
    *p=100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to allocate memory before accessing it.  Do as follows:

```
void sum(void)
{
    p = new int;
    *p=100;
}
```

Now you have to deallocate memory each time after you call the function sum;
so do it also after calling function sum:

```
delete p;
```

Comment: Now you also have to explain how to avoid a memory leak each time you call `sum`.

Comment: Why do i need the variable on heap? Its not huge..their is no question of scope of a literal...why cant i just get the variable on data section. The question is why? and what is happening..? Making the code work is not the goal here

Comment: @MiceZeusDig It's not about heap versus stack, it's about pointer versus non pointer. You probably just wanted `int p` as opposed to `int* p`.

Comment: You just declared a pointer  p, but it was not pointing to anywhere until you initialize with operator new

Comment: When you assign 100 to `p`, you're telling it to reference the memory location of 100, which it probably isn't allowed to do, hence the error.

Comment: @supercheetah please note p is a globally declared variable

Comment: @Steephen Yeah, I realized that shortly after I put in my initial post, and hoped to do a ninja edit.  Wasn't quite as sneaky as I thought.